# Can I use Numpy operations like reshape in Cython code without Python interaction?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have some Python code that I would like to speed up by using Cython.  I use a lot of Numpy operations in my script, like np.reshape and np.sum, when working with ndarrays.  When I use the operations in my code I don't know how to make them not interact with python, so they slow my Cython code down to about the speed Python is taking.

Here is an example.  Here is Python code that bins arrays by an arbitrary amount.

```
import numpy as np
def binarray (array,nbin):
    temp=array.reshape(int(array.shape[0]/nbin),nbin,int(array.shape[1]/nbin),nbin)
    temp=temp.sum(axis=(3,1))
    return temp
```

I have defined the data member types and declared the np.ndarray instances as described in the Cython documentation.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.double
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
def binarray (np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] array,int nbin):
    cdef int x0 = int(array.shape[0]/nbin)
    cdef int x2 = int(array.shape[1]/nbin)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] temp = np.zeros([x0,nbin,x2,nbin], dtype=DTYPE)
    temp = array.reshape(x0,nbin,x2,nbin)
    return temp.sum(axis=(3,1))
```

But I can't find anywhere how I might use a Numpy operation in Cython.  This is my first time using Cython, as I understand it Numpy arrays and operations on them are compiled in c so I thought I would be able to use them in Cython, is this the case? Or will I have to rewrite these functions myself?

Comment: You may find that the `numpy` implementations are highly optimised, and will be just as good (if not better) than what you can do in Cython. I would firstly think about profiling your code with `cprofile` to see exactly what is taking the most time.

Comment: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html; http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: I put some later functions through nested for loops, that is where most time is spent.  I use the np.sum function in the loop, and using python object data members seems to be the problem (since they are slow).  I hoped to learn how to use a Numpy operation inside of a function in Cython in a simpler function before going after more complex functions.  I gave this example because it was simpler to explain and I haven't yet worked through converting later code to Cython.

Comment: Don't expect any speed up in `binarray`.  In `numpy`, `reshape` is a trivial operation.  And `sum` is already compiled.

Comment: I've added a `nditer` example.

Answer (score 0):

So this function is supposed to do something like this:

```
In [474]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
In [475]: arr
Out[475]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
In [476]: binarray(arr,2)
Out[476]: 
array([[14, 22, 30],
       [62, 70, 78]])
```

Times don't look too shabby to me (this is on a relatively old laptop):

```
In [483]: timeit binarray(arr,2)
The slowest run took 4.93 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 µs per loop
In [484]: arr=np.ones((1000,1000),int)
In [485]: timeit binarray(arr,50)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.96 ms per loop
In [486]: timeit binarray(arr,100)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
In [487]: timeit binarray(arr,10)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.91 ms per loop
```

For reference, `sum` without reshaping:

```
In [489]: timeit arr.sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.28 ms per loop
```

And the minor reshape cost:

```
In [551]: %%timeit arr=np.ones((1000,1000));nbin=100
   temp = arr.reshape(int(arr.shape[0]/nbin), nbin, int(arr.shape[1]/nbin), nbin)
     ...: 
...
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.55 µs per loop
```

======================

I'd suggest working through this `nditer` turtorial, all the way to the cython implementation:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Here's a test of concept - using `nditer` to sum on 2 axes:

```
In [543]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
In [544]: res = np.zeros((2,3),int)
In [545]: it = np.nditer([arr.reshape(2,2,3,2),res.reshape(2,1,3,1)], 
    flags=['reduce_ok','external_loop'],
    op_flags=[['readonly'],['readwrite']])
In [546]: for x,y in it:
     ...:     print(x,y)
     ...:     y[...] += x
     ...:     
[0 1] [0 0]
[2 3] [0 0]
[4 5] [0 0]
[6 7] [1 1]
[8 9] [5 5]
[10 11] [9 9]
[12 13] [0 0]
[14 15] [0 0]
[16 17] [0 0]
[18 19] [25 25]
[20 21] [29 29]
[22 23] [33 33]
In [547]: res
Out[547]: 
array([[14, 22, 30],
       [62, 70, 78]])
```

In Cython that has a chance of being as fast as `temp.sum(axis=(3,1))`.